# Dynamically child component in parent

Tags: angular, vmware-clarity

I'm building an app with Angular4 and Vmware's Clarity UI for Angular. I have a main header for navigating the app.
There are some views within the app, that don't need a sidebar and other that do.
I want to display a sidebar specific to a particular view if the view has one, when a user navigates to it.
I'm also using module level routing in my application.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { MainComponent } from './main.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '', component: MainComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: 'dashboard',
                loadChildren: './dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule',
                data: {
                    title: 'Dashboard',
                    showSideNav: false
                }
            },
            {
                path: 'sales',
                loadChildren: './sales/sales.module#SalesModule',
                data: {
                    title: 'Sales',
                    showSideNav: true
                }
            }
        ]
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class MainRoutingModule { }
```

This is MainComponent

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, NavigationEnd, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-main',
    templateUrl: './main.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./main.component.scss']
})
export class MainComponent implements OnInit {

    showSideNav: Boolean = false;

    constructor(public router: Router, public activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) { }

    setSidenavState() {
        this.router.events
            .filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
            .map(() => this.activatedRoute)
            .map(route => {
                while (route.firstChild) {
                    route = route.firstChild;
                }

                return route;
            })
            .filter(route => route.outlet === 'primary')
            .mergeMap(route => route.data)
            .subscribe((event) => { 
                this.showSideNav = event['showSideNav'];
                console.log(this.showSideNav);
            });
    }
    ngOnInit() {
        this.setSidenavState();
        if (this.router.url === '/') {
            this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
        }
    }

}
```

and this is the main template

```
<clr-main-container>
    <header class="header header-6">
        <div class="branding">
            <a routerLink="/dashboard" class="brand nav-link">
                <img src="assets/img/logo-white.png">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="header-nav">
            <a routerLink="/dashboard" routerLinkActive="active" class="nav-link nav-text">Dashboard</a>
            <a routerLink="/sales" routerLinkActive="active" class="nav-link nav-text">Sales</a>
            <a href="" class="nav-link nav-text">Purchases</a>
            <a href="" class="nav-link nav-text">Contacts</a>
            <a href="" class="nav-link nav-text">Reports</a>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div class="content-container">
        <div class="content-area">
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </div>
        <nav class="sidenav" *ngIf="showSideNav">
            <app-sidenav></app-sidenav>
        </nav>
    </div>
</clr-main-container>
```

Within the main component, i have setup like this

```
+-- dashboard
+-- sales
|   +-- sidenav
+-- sidenav
|   +-- sidenav.component.html
|   +-- sidenav.component.ts
+-- main-routing.module.ts
+-- main.component.html
+-- main.component.ts
+-- main.module.ts
```

My question is how do I inject a different sidenav component specific to a particular view into the `app-sidenav` component if the `showSideNav` property is set to `true`.
Any suggestions or links would be appreciated.

Comment: why not use `*ngIf` with necessary conditions ?

Comment: If the template is shared between different sidenav components, I suggest you put some config in your 'data' (defined in Routes) and pass it to sidenav component via Input props.

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner the sidenav components have different templates.

Comment: Then instead of setting showSideNav to true or false, have some sort of switch case and call different sidenav components as Abrar suggested

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner I'll try that and post my solution here

Answer (score 4):

I believe the cleanest way to solve your use case is simply to move a little bit of the layout to the actual routed component.
Right now, you have this in your main template:

```html
<div class="content-container">
    <div class="content-area">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
    <nav class="sidenav" *ngIf="showSideNav">
        <app-sidenav></app-sidenav>
    </nav>
</div>
```

and let's say you sales template looks like this:

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
```

By shifting down the sidenav *into* the routed components, your main template becomes:

```html
<div class="content-container">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

and your sales template becomes:

```html
<div class="content-area">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
</div>
<nav class="sidenav">
    <sales-sidenav></sales-sidenav>
</nav>
```

If a component doesn't have a sidenav, simply do not put the sidenav in its template. No need for an `*ngIf`. 
The result is that you don't pollute your routes with sidenav information anymore, you just leave it to the component that handles the route itself, becomes it's the one that should own the specific sidenav logic.